# Is it possible to put ternary conditional operator inside the other ternary conditional operator in jsx

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to do what I mentioned in topic. I tried all methods I found and I dont even know if it is possible. Could you please help me?

```
<>
          {
          (isLoading) ? 
          <CircularProgress /> 
          : 
          {isTablet ? <MobileMenu /> : <Menu />}
          <Box
            sx={{
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: { laptop: "row", mobile: "column" },
              justifyContent: "center",
              gap: "0px 100px",
              mt: {
                tablet: "40px"
              },
              maxWidth: "1920px",
              marginInline: "auto"
            }}
            onClick={() => {
              console.log(product);
            }}
          >
            {isMobile ? <MobileGallery /> : <Gallery />}
            <Description product={product} />
          </Box>}
          
    
        </>
```

Comment: can you please provide more details? an exemple of what are you in mind, trying to do etc

Comment: `isLoading` is true at start, after getting data from api it is false, so I want to display `CircularProgress ' first and after switching `isLoading` to true, the rest of sire, becuase it is in the main component

Answer (score 1):

Yes, any given component of the ternary conditional operator is an expression.  And since the ternary conditional operator *itself* is an expression, it can be used as any such component.  Expressions can be nested infinitely.

It appears that what you have is simply a JSX syntax error.  Simplifying what you're showing, this structure is incorrect:

```
{
  isLoading ? 
  <CircularProgress /> : 
  {isTablet ? <MobileMenu /> : <Menu />}
}
```

The "inner" set of curly braces are unnecessary and will break the language parsing.  At this point in the syntax it would be expecting `{` to indicate the start of an object literal, which isn't what the code is doing.

You can simply remove them:

```
{
  isLoading ? 
  <CircularProgress /> : 
  isTablet ? <MobileMenu /> : <Menu />
}
```

For clarity and/or personal preference you can also wrap that expression in parentheses:

```
{
  isLoading ? 
  <CircularProgress /> : 
  (isTablet ? <MobileMenu /> : <Menu />)
}
```

Indentation is another option to indicate the nested expressions:

```
{
  isLoading ? 
    <CircularProgress /> : 
    isTablet ?
      <MobileMenu /> :
      <Menu />
}
```